# Login failed for user 'my-PC\my'

Tags: sql-server, security

Why I have this error:

**Cannot open database "source" requested by the login. The login failed.**

Login failed for user 'my-PC\my'  ?.

I use "windows" mode. From visual I can access data, but when I run it (asp project) I get an error.I get this eror when replaced database in project with modified version from Management Studio (I modified only stored procedure that's not invoking in project). I read some articles and in security option allowed 'my-PC\my' all operations.No effect.

**EDIT:**

here is my connection string:

```
    "Server=(local);Database=source;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use connectionstring:

```
"Server=.\SqlExpress;Database=<fill in your database name>;Integrated Security=SSPI"
```

If not working, make an SQL server account and use this connectionstring:

```
"Server=.\SqlExpress;Database=<fill in your database name>;User ID=<fill in your username>;Password=<fill in your password>;"
```